# Javascript onclick

Tags: javascript

есть в теле скрипт который вызывает тизеры, но заранее я не могу в них вставить код. мне нужно что бы при onclick на этих элементах происходило что то...

```
<a class="ad-image-href-9076001"
```

как можно придумать код?

Comment: ничо не понял

Comment: добавлялся класс=ad-image-href-9076001 к <a> ? или что? не понятно

Comment: нет есть ява скрипт! который показывает тизеры нужно к <a class="ad-image-href-9076001" добавить onclick=

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/jty4x/

```
(function (){
    function onClick(evt/**Event*/){
            evt = (evt || window.event);
        var el = (evt.target || evt.srcElement);

        do {
            if( / ad-image-href-(\d+) /.test(' '+el.className+' ') ){
                // Ваш код
                alert("Bingo: " + RegExp.$1);

                // Отменяем действие по умолчанию (если нужно)
                if( evt.preventDefault ){ // 
                    evt.preventDefault();
                } else { // IE < 9
                    evt.returnValue = false;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        while( el = el.parentNode );
    }

    if( document.addEventListener ){
        document.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
    } else { // IE < 9
        document.attachEvent('onclick', onClick)
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

например вот:

```
function func() {
//некий код для onclick
}

//js html4 если один с классом ad-image-href-9076001
var obj = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var l = obj.length;
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
   if (obj[i].className == 'ad-image-href-9076001') {
      obj[i].onclick = func;
      break;
   }
}

//js html4 если несколько с классом ad-image-href-9076001
var obj = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var l = obj.length;
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    if (obj[i].className == 'ad-image-href-9076001') obj[i].onclick = func;
}

//js html5 - Если один с классом ad-image-href-9076001
var obj = document.querySelector('.ad-image-href-9076001');
if (obj != null) obj.onclick = func;

//js html5 - Если несколько
var obj = document.querySelectorAll('.ad-image-href-9076001');
var l = obj.length;
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
obj[i].onclick = func;
}

//jquery
$('.ad-image-href-9076001').click(func);
```

Если проблема, что некому вызвать эти процедуры, то setTimeout(ваша процедура или function(){}, время через сколько должна быть запущена в милисекундах)

Comment: setTimeout — facepalm.gif

Comment: ну уж лучше так )), а не setTimeout
$(document).ready(function(){
...
});

Comment: сказано было заранее не может менять, ready как бы не катит в этом случае

Comment: не работает почему то код. ничего не происходит. все варианты перепробывал

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wE8uD/

Comment: function func() {
alert('Защитано!');
}


function sss(){

var obj = document.querySelectorAll('.ad-image-href-9076001');
var l = obj.length;
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
obj[i].onclick = func;
}

setTimeout(sss(), 1000);


все правильно вызываю?

Comment: не работает на тизерке ничего не происходит в консоле ошибок чисто.

Comment: function func() { alert('Защитано!'); }
function sss(){
var obj = document.querySelectorAll('.ad-image-href-9076001'); var l = obj.length; for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) { obj[i].onclick = func; }}
setTimeout(sss, 1000);